# VirtualBox unable to start virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using windows 7 Ultimate with virtual Box 4.3.14 installed.
I created a virtual machine but when I start the virtual machine, I get this error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.

The virtual machine 'Ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

What is the problem with my virtual machine. Is there anything I have not done?

Comment: Can you provide the log files?  They should be located in the same directory as the VM files.

Comment: The VM files directories show no log files

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have an antivirus conflict. It looks like they have a test build to fix the issue.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615

https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-4.3.15-95663-Win.exe

Comment: Thanks I am going to try the test build. Yesterday I looked at the forum post provided above, and downgraded to version 3.1.8 and it worked good, but I want the latest version, and I am going to try that test build. Thanks again and I hope it works.

Comment: Yea, this actually works. I Installed the test build and now everything is OK. Thanks

Comment: do `VirtualBox Guest Additions` work for you when `3d Acceleration` is enabled on the Virtual Machine?